# How to modify magnifier small lens and bigger preview

Tags: magento2, xml, gallery

I have modified as follows

```
<var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">2</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width">150</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height">150</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>
```

It's working fine as expected. But I want smaller lens and bigger preview.

I tried to modify **.magnify-lens** class and **.magnifier-preview** class but could not come up with fine tuning.

Answer (score 2):

This is my settings I achieve smaller lens and bigger preview:

Yourvendor/YourTheme/view/etc.xml

```
<var name="magnifier">
    <var name="fullscreenzoom">2</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
    <var name="top">3</var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
    <var name="left">284</var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
    <var name="width">114</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
    <var name="height">114</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
    <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
    <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
    <var name="mode">outside</var> <!-- Zoom type (outside/inside) -->
</var>
```

and css to get proper zoom. 3 in example is big.

```
.magnifier-preview:not(.hidden) {
    zoom: 3;
}
```

**Instead of using CSS better add proper image - bigger and with better resolution. This will give you nice zoom and bigger image on magnifier.**

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I've just found the answer to making the preview image bigger.

Create your own view.xml file and add the large image config as below. This will then alter the size of the image that is used within the magnifier preview.

app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\etc\view.xml

```
    <image id="product_page_image_large" type="image">
        <width>1750</width>
        <height>1400</height>
        <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
        <frame>false</frame>
    </image>
```